# How can I use the external jars on JBoss 7?

Tags: jboss7.x

Now I can load jars which is under the EAR/lib.
But I want to put the jars to a common path, for other application to use.
I found that jboss-deployment-structure.xml file's  tag can do this.
But it doesn't work. I got the ClassNotFound exception.
I don't know why?

```
<deployment>
   <resources>
        <resource-root path="/common/test.jar" />
   </resources>
 </deployment>
```

Answer (score 11):

One way of using global libraries in different applications can be reached by making them available as modules. 
Therefor, extend the modules by the library you are providing as a server provider.

*Example:*
To make your `test.jar` available to all applications, create a folder with the modules name and a `main` subdirectory (e.g. `modules/commons/test/main`).

Place your library there and a module description file with the name `module.xml`.
Example content:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="commons.test">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="test.jar"/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

Now the library is available to all applications.
To get access to the module, your application has to define the dependency in the manifest.

Applications **MANIFEST.MF**:

---

```
Dependencies: commons.test
```

---

This can be also done by maven during build time.
Check https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7 for details

Please note that you're modifying the server itself. All applications using your module are depending on it. A application with a dependency to the module `commons.test` wont be deployed on a server which does not have this module provided.

Comment: Is that possible to do the same without touching the server (global) modules? i.e., creating modules inside EAR?

Comment: is there a possibility of wild card instead of specifying each library?