# JBoss 7 ClassNotFoundError

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

While trying to deploy new ear file IN JBoss 7 and tring to access a service I'm getting the following error:

> 16:17:39,114 ERROR
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/my-app-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT].[MyServicesBean]]
>   (http--10.232.165.117-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet
>   MyServicesBean threw exception: java.util.MissingResourceException:
>   Could not instantiate factory delegate, got exception(s):
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl
>   from [Module "deployment.my-app-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear:main" from
>   Service Module Loader] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl
>   from [Module "deployment.my-app-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear:main" from
>   Service Module Loader] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl from [Module
>   "deployment.my-app-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear:main" from Service Module
>   Loader]
>           at weblogic.xml.jaxp.Utils.getDelegate(Utils.java:28) [wlfullclient5-12.1.3.0.0.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>           at weblogic.xml.jaxp.WebLogicTransformerFactory.(WebLogicTransformerFactory.java:79)
>   [wlfullclient5-12.1.3.0.0.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>           at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryTransformerFactory.(RegistryTransformerFactory.java:62)
>   [wlfullclient5-12.1.3.0.0.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>           at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistrySAXTransformerFactory.(RegistrySAXTransformerFactory.java:12)
>   [wlfullclient5-12.1.3.0.0.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
>           at __redirected.__TransformerFactory.(__TransformerFactory.java:111) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]

Can you please suggest how to solve this ?

Comment: Are you using Xalan? Does JBoss see this library?

Comment: I am new for JBoss too. Read in the Internet how to add libs to JBoss. May be this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581157/error-in-referencing-a-dependency-jar-file-from-jboss-7-1?lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is probably because you don't have a xalan library in your project.

So, either you can add it to the project from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xalan/xalan/2.7.2 or you can use the one which is included in the JBoss server by creating a jboss-deployment-structure.xml file:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>            
        <exclusions>            
            <module name="org.apache.xalan" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

In case you have any problems - add xerces library as well:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>            
        <exclusions>            
            <module name="org.apache.xalan" />
            <module name="org.apache.xerces" /> 
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Hope this helps.

P.S. JBoss documentation about Class Loading in JBoss: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7