# Jboss AS7 - How to create module.xml for external libraries?

Tags: jboss7.x

I have multiple .ear projects which use multiple libraries. So I need to make those as common and add those in the module. So Is there any easy way to create module.xml as I need to create module.xml for each library?

Also do I need to define the dependency for each library in module.xml?

Please let me know if there is any easy way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to create 'module.xml' for each library.

Create a single module and put all libraries there and mention it in resource-root. Also mention any module dependencies (if no, ignore it).

Example module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.test.myownresteasy">
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
    </properties>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="activation-1.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="httpcore-4.1.2.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jettison-1.3.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="scannotation-1.0.3.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="httpclient-4.1.2.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jaxrs-api-2.3.2.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jul-to-slf4j-stub-1.0.0.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="resteasy-jaxb-provider-2.3.2.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="resteasy-jettison-provider-2.3.2.Final.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Insert dependencies here -->
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Copy your modules to '$JBOSS/modules' directory which makes it as global module.

Refer:
[How can I use the external jars on JBoss 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662456/how-can-i-use-the-external-jars-on-jboss-7)

Comment: Hi Sriram, thanks for the update. In fact, this is what I finally did. However, if I use some third party libraries which could be defined as module then I need to create those as a separate module right. I know ether way it works fine, but as a standard we need to create modules and define in the module xml right?

Comment: Yes, its better to have a separate module which can manage all your third party dependencies across projects.