# FileNotFoundException when trying to retrieve spring bean file within jar

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, war

I am trying to setup an ear, common.jar (includes common code), multiple wars which depend on the common.jar. I am having an issue with a common-beans.xml file which is within common.jar.

A snippet of the web.xml file within one of the war is as follows:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>locatorFactorySelector</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:common-beans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>parentContextKey</param-name>
    <param-value>commonContext</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I receive the following stacktrace on startup of jboss server

```
[0m[0m10:14:10,180 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [common-beans.xml]
[0m[31m10:14:10,181 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Unable to initialize group definition. Group resource name [classpath:common-beans.xml], factory key [commonContext]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [common-beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [common-beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:386) [spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.loadParentContext(ContextLoader.java:566) [spring-web-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:303) [spring-web-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:161) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:59) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:94) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [common-beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [common-beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341) [spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) [spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174) [spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209) [spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180) [spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243) [spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127) [spring-context-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93) [spring-context-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130) [spring-context-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:539) [spring-context-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451) [spring-context-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.access.ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.initializeDefinition(ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:143) [spring-context-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:381) [spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [common-beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:171) [spring-core-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328) [spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    ... 27 more
```

The file is within the jar file when deployed to the server in the path core-1.0.jar/common-beans.xml (but the jar is already exploded but I am not sure why yet).

Is the common-beans.xml file visible to the war file?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to share jar's with multiple ear's or war's is to put the common jar into the modules folder and use a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` in the individuals to refer the common module.

Refer [Jboss Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745978/jboss-as7-how-to-create-module-xml-for-external-libraries) on how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will look into this at some point but I am not sure I need to do this to achieve the above. Is that correct?