# adding jars as deployment in WildFly 10

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, deployment, wildfly-10

Is there a way, we can deploy jars as a library/deployment in `WildFly 10` like we can do it in `weblogic` server?. OR can we place the jars in any folder of server and define those dependencies as `provided`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I got the way to deploy `jar`s on `WildFly 10` server rather than making part of the war file is define below:

1) Put all your jars in `wildfly\modules\system\layers\base\com\abcProject\main`
and place a file named `module.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.abcProject">
<resources>
    <resource-root path="aspectjrt-1.6.8.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="aspectjweaver-1.6.8.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="aopalliance-1.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="guava-18.0.jar"/>
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="javaee.api"/>
    <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.vfs"/>
</dependencies>
```

Where `resources` are all those `jars` present in your `abcProject/main` folder and `dependencies` are all those `jars` on which your `jars` are dependent and are present in `wildfly\modules\system\layers\base` folders.

2) Then in your project add a file named `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` in `WEB-INF` folder with the following conents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="com.abcProject" >
            <imports>
                <include path="META-INF**"/>
                <include path="org**"/>
            </imports>
        </module>
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
```

3) Now set `scope` of all those `dependencies` in your `pom` files as `provided` that you have placed `jars` in `abcProject/main` folder.

That's all now run your project it will get all `jar`s from server and will not include in `war` file during compilation.

Comment: Are we sure this is an optimal answer? You can define modules in the deployment folders directly. I dont think it is optimal to add modules to the wildfly system folder, which is akin to adding jars to the JRE's lib folder.

Comment: But then can you define multiple modules in standalone deployment folder? Can you provide me a link for it's implementation? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To add external jars as a "library" in Jboss/Wildfly, you can define it as a module in your installation, or add it to an existing module.

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662456/how-can-i-use-the-external-jars-on-jboss-7) for more details on how to add a module in Wildfly.

Comment: Ok but then will I remove the all dependencies like spring etc or write it with provided scope?

Comment: I actually want to make a war file of all my jars and deploy on server, can it be done?

Comment: Yes, you can remove the dependencies from the EAR by specifiying a provided scope in the POM. I'm not sure about the global war file, you can however specify multiple jars in one jboss module (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745978/jboss-as7-how-to-create-module-xml-for-external-libraries)

Comment: Ok @Leo Thanks. I will try this approach too and will search for war module.