# Migration of my application from Glassfish 2.1. to JBoss 7.1.3 -Related to user shared lib

Tags: java, jboss, glassfish, ear

Good day!

My application is running fine in Glass fish 2.1. It is .ear file. I am using more configuration file like xsl,xsd,apache log4j xml and some property files to my application. So I have created shared library in my disk say C:/SharedLib and put all my configuration files in this location. In glassfish I will give this location in my Application Server-->JVM settings-->path settings --> Classpath prefix --- C:/SharedLib

I will use all the property files,jar files and xsl,xsd from that location(C:/SharedLib. My application (.ear ) contains ejb and war file.

My question is how i can use same configuration in my Jboss 7.1.3? Is there any way without changing my code in my application .ear?

Comment: See [How can I use the external jars on JBoss 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662456/how-can-i-use-the-external-jars-on-jboss-7)

Comment: Paul,Thanks for your reply. I will work around and make use of it.I have some xsl,xsd and property files. Is there any way to put them in a location (say C:/SharedLib) and my application should pick my configuration files from that location? Is there any configuration in Jboss AS?

Comment: Packaged into a JAR and add it too.

Comment: It is working Paul thanks...But i will change the some property files frequently ..Then each time i need to change and convert  entire folder to jar . Currently i will do what you have suggested..If you find any way to put them in a folder and run my application please help me..